# Groovy and python not seeing string in the same way

Tags: python-2.7, jenkins, groovy

I have a list of strings acting as parameters in a script that’s created in groovy and called from the cli.

I groom these strings from a multi line input in Jenkins like so

```
F=Files.tokenize(“/n”)
Script.appendflags(—files=${F})
Script.exec()
```

On the cli for some reason it looks like this.                          '—files=[file1,’  ‘file2]’

The python then treats the first quote as an escape character and only keeps [file1,

Is there anyway to tokenize without getting into this issue? And if not, is there anyway to get around this otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those wondering, I eventually ran through a loop in groovy appending a --files=files then --files=files2, and on the python side set the action to "append", which allowed me to get around this strange issue